# MVC6, tsd and typings

Tags: asp.net, typescript, asp.net-core-mvc, tsd

Since **TSD** is officially deprecated and wanting to look into the future, what is the structure/practice to using **typings** in MVC6 framework? Any pointers will be appreciated and thank you in advance.

I tried using a tutorial from the **typings** website and ended up with this set of files (see attached) and not sure how to include it into the MVC6 project (what to and not to include) and reference it in a **TypeScript** file.

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd/issues/269

https://github.com/typings/typings

[image]

Comment: The screenshot doesn't show anything specific to tsd or typings.  Rather, it shows typescript definition files installed by the typescript npm package.  Additionally, as far as I remember (going back to December last year), MVC6 has no reliance (or inclusion) on typescript, or tsd for that matter.  A quick look at the [repo](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc) seems to confirm no existence of typescript files, or tsd.  As such its a bit hard to understand what you're asking here.  For the record, tsd and typings are only needed for compiling typescript.

Comment: I searched for *.d.ts in the Visual Studio solution which I thought were type files but I think these were created by the VS template. In MVC5 I use to add the TypeScript feature and type files using nuget. In MVC6, the type files don't install using this method anymore and it looks like tsd or typings using npm is the recommended practice.  So, I'm looking for the scaffolding to support using TypeScript in MVC6. As of now, the typescript tutorial is still in the works: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/client-side/typescript.html. Still researching... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot doesn't show anything specific to tsd or typings.

That said, typings has a migration guide available online : https://github.com/typings/typings/blob/master/docs/tsd.md